# How to stop mirroring my site content in another site

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have a video related wordpress site and someone is mirroring my the entire site in his domain like this:

- My site: `example.com`
- He is using like this: `hisite.com/c/pm.php?url=http://www.example.com/?p=7232`
  (this is the example of 1 post)

I tried to add these codes into my `header.php` (tried separately):

```
if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]) && strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"], "www.mysite.com") === false)
    die();
```

and this:

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && !empty($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) && strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'], 'hissite.com') !== false) {
    die('Not Found 404');
}
```

But it has not worked.

Earlier I tried this snippet with `.htaccess` file:

```
Header append X-FRAME-OPTIONS "DENY"
```

but that also failed.

Comment: I changed the term "embedding" to more general "mirroring" as the way it's probably done is not by an i-frame linking to your side or anything similar but by downloading your site's content to the other site's server and then displaying it from there.

Comment: Thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can't limit access with testing $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] because there is many methods to pass HTTP_REFERER through crawler scripts. Maybe IP address restriction can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How can restrict his IP?

Comment: You can write simple code to show user IP in your page. Then you can open this page from mirroring site. You will see the IP from throgh mirror site crawl you site. After this you can add this IP to black list from firewall or show empty page if request was from this IP.